# Explanation for the energy method used here

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am reading a paper where the authors prove
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \Vert f \Vert_{H^4} (t)\leq C\Vert f \Vert^5_{H^4}(t) $$
Where $f=f(x,t)$ and $H^4$ stands for the usual Sobolev space. Using Gronwall's inequality, they obtain $\Vert f \Vert _{H^4}$ is bounded up to a time $T_*=T(\Vert f_0\Vert _{H^4})$. Now, they say **applying energy method the local existence follows**. I don't understand what the meant by 'energy method'.

Can someone explain what 'energy method' is here?

Comment: What is the PDE they are studying? The answer probably depends on the type of PDE.

Comment: is the Muskat problem. The proof is in the paper named 'Contour Dynamics of Incompressible 3d fluids in a porous medium with different densities' by D. Córdoba and F. Gancedo. See theorem 4.1.

Comment: They do say "see [5] for more details" at the beginning of the proof. Maybe that book has a similar argument in full detail.

Comment: Yes, but I cant find that reference.

Comment: Can anyone provide that paper??

Comment: @R.N.Marley: if you need help finding a reference, please do include the full bibliographic info in your post. If the reference is to a book, your local librarian may be able to help you track down the publication.